# How to go towards this functions and defining whether injective or surjective

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

$G(x) :   \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ given by $G(x) = 2x+5 \, \, \forall x \in \mathbb{N}$.

$H(x) :   \mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z} $ given by $H(x) = 10 \,\,  \forall \,x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I am not familiar with this notations. However, I got an idea whether injective or surjective. And finally, are these functions? I think they are since they pass the vertical line test. But, not really sure if there are restrictions since we are discussing about discrete math.

Answer (score 2):

I think it means that $G$ is a subset of $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$, meaning that it is a set of ordered pairs of natural numbers. In other words, $G(x)$ takes $x$ as a natural number and returns a natural number, or in yet another explanation, $G:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$. You showed us bad notation, but I think I have explained what it probably means. Are you sure that what I wrote last is not what you were given? There is a difference of just one symbol.

$G$ is indeed a function from $\Bbb N$ into $\Bbb N$, since if $x$ is a natural number so is $G(x)$. It is injective, since different $x$'s will give you different results. However, it is not surjective, since for example there is no natural number $x$ that gives you $G(x)=1$, or for that matter, $G(x)=10$.

See if you can do the same kind of analysis for $H(x)$. If you get stuck, let us know how far you got and we can help you go farther.